# Need assistance deriving a complicated function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, summation, partial-derivative

I'm trying to prove a formula regarding the derivative of a somewhat complicated function.

$w \in \mathbb R^M$ is our variable, we have a set of $M$ functions $\phi_j: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a given vector $x \in \mathbb R^N$ and another given vector $t \in \mathbb R^N$ and some parameter $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

I'm trying to prove that the gradient of $E(w) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N[t_i-\sum_{j=1}^Mw_j\phi_j(x_i)]^2+\frac{1}{2}\lambda\sum_{k=1}^{M}w_k^2$ is zero when $w = (\Phi^T\Phi+\lambda I)^{-1}\Phi^Tt$ where $\Phi_{nm}=\phi_m(x_n)$

I didn't get very far.

I derived $E(w)$ with respect to $w_r$ and I was hoping I could represent $w_r$ since $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_r} = 0$, and I could then generlize it and find a matrix form for $\nabla E$.

$\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_r} = \sum_{i=1}^N[t_i-\sum_{j=1}^Mw_j\phi_j(x_i)]\sum_{k=1}^N\phi_r(x_k)+\lambda w_r$ and here I'm stuck. I know I need to set this to zero, but I can't seem to isolate $w_r$.

I'd appreciate any help going forward. Please note that I need to reach the desired result via setting the gradient to zero, so simply calculating $\nabla E((\Phi^T\Phi+\lambda I)^{-1}\Phi^Tt)$ and seeing its equal to zero is no good.

Another approach, perhaps simpler, is instead of the sums, represent $E$ somehow as a product of matrices. I didn't get very far there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can be written in matrix form
$$E = \frac{1}{2}(\Phi w-t):(\Phi w-t) + \frac{\lambda}{2} w:w$$
where the colon denotes the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

Apply the elementary law for differentials
$$\eqalign{
  f &= X:X \cr
 df &= 2X:dX \cr
}$$
to find the differential of $E$ 
$$\eqalign{
 dE &= (\Phi w-t):\Phi\,dw + \lambda w:dw \cr
    &= (\Phi^T\Phi w-\Phi^T t + \lambda w):dw \cr
}$$
Since $dE = \big(\frac{\partial E}{\partial w}:dw\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial E}{\partial w} &= \Phi^T\Phi w-\Phi^T t  + \lambda w \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero and solving for $w$ yields
$$\eqalign{
 (\Phi^T\Phi+\lambda I)\,w  &= \Phi^T t  \cr
 w  &= (\Phi^T\Phi+\lambda I)^{-1}\,\Phi^T t  \cr
}$$